# Filling NAs NOCB (next observation carried backward)

Tags: r

My data is a return from a KDB database query and comes in the form of a list of lists 
If I str(myData)

```
   $ INL:List of 9
  ..$ : int [1:1920] 34200000 34215000 34230000 34245000 34260000 34275000 34290000     
  ..$ : Date[1:1920], format: ")*//-06-22" ")*//-06-22" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:1920] "" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ : num [1:1920] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ : int [1:1920] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ : num [1:1920] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ : int [1:1920] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ : num [1:1920] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ : num [1:1920] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...

at [[1]]  i have a time
at [[2]] i have date 
at [[3]] i have a stock ticker 
at [[4]] i have a bid price
at [[5]] i have bid qty
at [[6]] i have an ask price
at [[7]] i have an ask qty
```

the problem i am facing is that the first 20 or so returns are NaN's and there could be further NaN's in the output.

I would like to replace the NaN's with the results in the first row where there isnt an NAN ie if our list of lists looked like this

```
[1]     [2]           [3]    [4]   [5]     [6]    [7]
09:30   Nan           Nan    Nan   Nan     Nan    Nan 
09:31   Nan           Nan    Nan   Nan     Nan    Nan 
09:32   2013:01:01    ABC    100   50      101    35 
09:33   2013:01:01    ABC    100   50      102    60
09:34   Nan           Nan    Nan   Nan     Nan    Nan 
09:35   2013:01:01    ABC    99   40      101    50


This would come out as follows:
[1]     [2]           [3]    [4]   [5]     [6]    [7]
09:30   2013:01:01    ABC    100   50      101    35 
09:31   2013:01:0     ABC    100   50      101    35 
09:32   2013:01:01    ABC    100   50      101    35 
09:33   2013:01:01    ABC    100   50      102    60
09:34   2013:01:01    ABC    99   40       101    50 
09:35   2013:01:01    ABC    99   40       101    50
```

ie the Nan'a are replaced by the next valid entry in the same coloumn(list)

Answer (score 3):

Use `zoo::na.locf`.

```
## if your data is in a data frame you can do it like this 
your_data = zoo::na.locf(your_data, fromLast = TRUE)

## if your data is a list, do this
your_data = lapply(your_data, zoo::na.locf, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) and [`rle`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html):

```r
d <- c(NaN, NaN, 3, 3, 4, NaN, 3,4)
d2 <- ifelse(is.nan(d), -999, d)  # -999 is the sentinel value
r.d2 <- rle(d2)
invalid.posn <- which(r.d2$values == -999)
r.d2$values[ invalid.posn ] <- r.d2$values[ invalid.posn + 1 ]
# If there are NaNs at the end, then the last values will be NA 
inverse.rle(r.d2)

# [1] 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4
```